# TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined (Observable)

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following (part of a TypeScript/Angular2/SPFx project):

```
// Populate the regulatory documents dropdown
this.regulatoryDocumentsService.fetchRegulatoryDocumentsData().subscribe(
    data => { this.regulatoryDocumentsData = data },
    err => { window.console && console.log(err) }
);
```

Where:

```
public fetchRegulatoryDocumentsData(): Observable<RegulatoryDocument[]> {
    var choicesArray: Array<RegulatoryDocument> = new Array<RegulatoryDocument>();

    // Local environment
    if (Environment.type === EnvironmentType.Local)
    {
        // Send dummy data to the form - this works
        window.console && console.log("fetchRegulatoryDocumentsData(): Local workbench in use");
        choicesArray.push(new RegulatoryDocument(1,"Document 1"));
        choicesArray.push(new RegulatoryDocument(2, "Document 2"));
        choicesArray.push(new RegulatoryDocument(3, "Document 3"));
        return Observable.of<RegulatoryDocument[]>(choicesArray);
    }
    else if (Environment.type == EnvironmentType.SharePoint || 
          Environment.type == EnvironmentType.ClassicSharePoint)
    {
        // fetchRegulatoryDoocumentsData() is undefined. when I try to subscribe to it.
        pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle('Regulatory Documents').items.get().then((choices: any[]) => {
            window.console && console.log("choices ...");
            window.console && console.log(choices);

            if (choices) {
                //choices.forEach((choice) => {
                //    choices.push(new Rating(choice));
                //});
                //Array.from(choices).forEach(function (child) {
                //    window.console && console.log(child)
                //});

                [].slice.call(choices).forEach(choice => {
                   choicesArray.push(new RegulatoryDocument(choice.ID, choice.Title));
                });
            }
            return Observable.of<RegulatoryDocument[]>(choicesArray);
        });
    }
}
```

However, an issue occurs if `Environment.type != EnvironmentType.Local`. The when I try to subscribe, it says that cannot subscribe to undefined. I suspect this is because of the nested PNP promise. Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`lists.getByTitle('Regulatory Documents').items.get().then(...);` in your code will return a promise that holds an observable not an observable.

```
else if (Environment.type == EnvironmentType.SharePoint || 
          Environment.type == EnvironmentType.ClassicSharePoint)
    {
        // fetchRegulatoryDoocumentsData() is undefined. when I try to subscribe to it.
    return Observable.create( (observer: any) => {
        pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle('Regulatory Documents').items.get().then((choices: any[]) => {



            window.console && console.log("choices ...");
            window.console && console.log(choices);

            if (choices) {
                //choices.forEach((choice) => {
                //    choices.push(new Rating(choice));
                //});
                //Array.from(choices).forEach(function (child) {
                //    window.console && console.log(child)
                //});

                [].slice.call(choices).forEach(choice => {
                   choicesArray.push(new RegulatoryDocument(choice.ID, choice.Title));
                });
            }
            observer.next(choicesArray);
        });
    });
  }
}
```

or use promises in all your code:

```
this.regulatoryDocumentsService.fetchRegulatoryDocumentsData().then(
    data => { this.regulatoryDocumentsData = data },
    err => { window.console && console.log(err) }
);
```

service

```
public fetchRegulatoryDocumentsData(): Observable<RegulatoryDocument[]> {
    var choicesArray: Array<RegulatoryDocument> = new Array<RegulatoryDocument>();

    // Local environment
    if (Environment.type === EnvironmentType.Local)
    {
        // Send dummy data to the form - this works
        window.console && console.log("fetchRegulatoryDocumentsData(): Local workbench in use");
        choicesArray.push(new RegulatoryDocument(1,"Document 1"));
        choicesArray.push(new RegulatoryDocument(2, "Document 2"));
        choicesArray.push(new RegulatoryDocument(3, "Document 3"));
        return Promise<RegulatoryDocument[]>.resolve(choicesArray);
    }
    else if (Environment.type == EnvironmentType.SharePoint || 
          Environment.type == EnvironmentType.ClassicSharePoint)
    {
        // fetchRegulatoryDoocumentsData() is undefined. when I try to subscribe to it.
        pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle('Regulatory Documents').items.get().then((choices: any[]) => {
            window.console && console.log("choices ...");
            window.console && console.log(choices);

            if (choices) {
                //choices.forEach((choice) => {
                //    choices.push(new Rating(choice));
                //});
                //Array.from(choices).forEach(function (child) {
                //    window.console && console.log(child)
                //});

                [].slice.call(choices).forEach(choice => {
                   choicesArray.push(new RegulatoryDocument(choice.ID, choice.Title));
                });
            }
            return choicesArray;
        });
    }
}
```